# Invalid Swift Support / Invalid Binary for iMessage app upload

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have tried nine ways from Sunday to submit a first build of a new iMessage app to iTunes Connect using Xcode 8 GM on El Capitan 10.11.6, and am at a complete loss. I realize there are several other SO posts regarding invalid Swift support - I have tried the suggestions and solutions from them all, to no avail. After completing a successful build upload each time, moments later I receive an "invalid binary" email, stating:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreLocation.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib,
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib,
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the
>   expected location /Payload/[AppName].app/Frameworks. Move the file
>   to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public
>   (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.

Some notes on the app and what I've attempted:

- This is a pure Swift 3 iMessage app; there is no main container app.
- I have unzipped the IPA file I've created from the xcarchive, and the swift dylib files are in fact in /Payload/[AppName].app/Frameworks as expected.
- I've tried creating xcarchives and IPAs using both Xcode and fastlane gym.
- I've tried uploading builds using both iTunes and Application Loader.
- I've cleaned the project and the build directory before each upload.
- I've incremented the build number each time I upload.
- I am not using CocoaPods nor Carthage. I am using only git submodules with Xcode sub-projects.
- I've tried recreating a fresh new project from scratch, copying over only my project source files.
- I have no special build scripts or configuration that I've changed in build settings.
- That said, I have attempted to toggle on and off "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" in both the main app target and the Messages extensions target.
- I've tried praying Apple will one day take a hard look at how convoluted and tedious their build and submission process is.

I'm only led to believe that somewhere during the final processing/build upload process, either locally on my machine or server-side in iTunes Connect, the Swift dylib files are mysteriously getting removed. Before I file a Radar bug, can anyone else either confirm this issue, or know how to work around/fix it? I will totally buy you a beer if you can save me and others from this silly frustration. Thanks!

Comment: I have similar issues, even though I use CocoaPods. In my case all the files are on correct places, when I'm inspecting files locally. So I'll dupe the radar.